# PHP Post name wildcard - $_POST['var_'.*];

Tags: php

Is there some kind of wildcard I can use to create POST vars that start with a specific string?

Essentially, I am trying to capture any POST that contains bSortable_(wildcard) as the name.

bSortable_1
bSortable_2
bSortable_3

I am doing this for a library jquery datatables.

http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get post variables to an array, than iterate through it while you filter.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $pos = strpos($key , "bSortable_");
  if ($pos === 0){
    // do something with $value
  }
}
```

Comment: On a technical note, that doesn't check whether or not bSortable_ is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: than check if $pos equals to 0 :) Thanks for warning.

Comment: Need if ($pos === 0); strpos() returns false if the string is not there.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Use `name="bSortable[name_here]"` or some permutation thereof.</strike> PHP can accept multidimensional POST parameters.

If that's not possible, you're going to have to loop though your available POSTed variables, and check the key names, like so:

```
<?php foreach($_POST as $key => $val) if(strpos($key, 'bSortable_') === 0) .... ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo want to create or read ? not clear your question.

to read, here it is my PHP 5.3 solution

```
$sortables = array_filter($_POST, function($e){
  return preg_match('/^bSortable/', $e);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately `array_filter` is passed the array value not the array key so in your example `$e` would be a value not a key.

Comment: $sortables = array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($_POST), function($e){
  return preg_match('/^bSortable/', $e);
}));

Comment: Um, there's definitely easier ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(substr($key,0,10) == 'bSortable_'){
        //Do something here with the $value.
    }
}
```

Now you can make sure it does get the first part of the POST key, and not somewhere in the middle of key.