# php match variable names using wildcard

Tags: php, variables, wildcard

I need to check for the existence of a variable.

Variables are not necessarily created in order 1.2.3.  They could be created 2.4.3.1.  These are also not created at the same time on the same page.  So I am just wanted to check for the existence of the variable.

```
$_SESSION['rule1']
$_SESSION['rule2']
$_SESSION['rule3']
$_SESSION['rule4']

<?
 if(isset($_SESSION['rule'.*wildcard*'])) {

 do something

 }
?>
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.  The answer probably lies in REGEX but I am horrible with REGEX.

Comment: yes I reworded the question.

Comment: In this particular case, rule4 could be created before rule1.  So I just need to know if rule* exists. and rule* could be 1-??.  So first instance of the variable existing wins the game.

Comment: ok so.  There is a series of web forms.  The user can "select" any item to edit.  So lets say they edit Item 3.  Once they finish editing this "rule3" now exists.  So since they selected item 3 instead of item1 I cannot detect if rule1 exists or not.  I need to detect if any of the "rule*" variables are now existent. If they are I need to do some things.

Comment: I guess I can just use a for loop.  Detect the number of items and loop through each one until [rule.$i] exists, do some things then exit the for loop.  I just thought that was more effort than something like a wildcard scenerio.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112167/php-post-name-wildcard-postvar So, it seems that you will need to check $_SESSION array....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know need to know which rule* key is in the session array, only if any of them are present, then you could try this:

```
<?php

function prefixExists(array $assoc_array, $prefix)
{
    $length = strlen($prefix);
    foreach ($assoc_array as $key => $unused)
    {
        if (strncmp($key, $prefix, $length) === 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Testing as follows:

```
session_start();
var_dump(prefixExists($_SESSION, 'rule'));
$_SESSION['rule3'] = 'some value from form';
var_dump(prefixExists($_SESSION, 'rule'));
```

Gives output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Comment: @astrangeloop - slightly faster approach `strpos($key, $prefix) === 0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with the use of `preg_match`:

```
function arrayHasSimilarKey(array $array, $matchKey)
{
    $pattern = '/' . str_replace('*', '.*', $matchKey) . '/i';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) { echo $key.PHP_EOL;
        if (preg_match($pattern, $key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$testArray = ['abc' => 1, 'test_1' => 1, 'test_2' => 1, 'test2_1' => 1, 'test3_2' => 1];
$tests = [
    0 => arrayHasSimilarKey($testArray, 'test*'),    // true
    1 => arrayHasSimilarKey($testArray, 'test2*_2'), // false
    2 => arrayHasSimilarKey($testArray, 'test3*'),   // true
    3 => arrayHasSimilarKey($testArray, 'test3*_1'), // false
    4 => arrayHasSimilarKey($testArray, '*_2')       // false
];

var_dump($tests);
```

In your case, `$testArray` would be `$_SESSION`